# How to add class to submenu in wordpress wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom HTML theme which i was about to convert into a WP theme. While converting i had some issues in menu part where menu have submenus. I tried to code `wp_nav_menu()`
function button the submenu doesn't appear well.

Below is my simple html code for the menu.

```
<div class="menu-nav" id="fdw">
<div class="nav">
<ul id="MainMenuItem">
<li><a id="about" href='aboutus.aspx' class="about-link">About Us</a>
<ul  class="sub_menu-adver">
<li><a href='aboutus.aspx?url=Executive-Team&id=et'>Executive Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So i tried to convert this menu into WP menu:

```
<div class="menu-nav" id="fdw">
<div class="nav">
<ul id="MainMenuItem">
<?php
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => 'fdw',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => '',
'container_id'    => 'MainMenuItem',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => 'MainMenuItem',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '', 
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); 

?>
```

Here is the [demo](http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/) for the website.

Where you can see the menu above is the About us menu which is hard coded HTML code and below menus starting from about us to website development.They are not displaying well and the submenu for projects are not showing like above About us menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but the code of your Wordpress menu looks like this:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/?page_id=7">About Us</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/?page_id=5">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-9 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/?page_id=9">Projects</a>
<ul class="children" style="/* display: none; */">
<li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/?page_id=17">SEO</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://crazywebtech.com/projects/psdToWp/?page_id=15">Website Development</a></li></ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So you wanted to "add a class" to the submenu, it has the class already of .children.

Copy-paste the styles from .sub_menu-adver to .children and you will get the submenu you want. This isn't exactly what you asked but it should do the trick.

Comment: While this doesn't answer his question it is probably a viable solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is my custom Walker class. You'll need to learn how to use it to customize the WP nav output. Notice the last few lines where a class is outputed. This is the method to add classes to each esection.

```
// Walker Class
class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu sub-one\">\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: where to add the walker class in function.php ? and how can add my item to that can you guide me to  how to add my submenu class above mention

Comment: I can't see your code so this is all hypothetical: Add the walker above your wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); function. Add your class within this line in the Walker -> $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu sub-one\">\n";

Comment: Did you try all the things I mentioned above? Email me at benracicotATyahoo.com